# Outlook Mailitem as Zip Attachment in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, c#-ziparchive

I would like to zip a Outlook Mailitem and add it as attachment to a new mail. This is what i got so far:

```
newmail.Attachments.Add(mailItem, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem);
```

Tested and works so far if i add the plain email as attachment. But how can I create a new ZipArchive from a MailItem?

Comment: Are you struggling to zip mailItem with c#, or are you struggling to attach a zipped item to mailItem?

Comment: I am struggeling to zip a mailitem with c#

Comment: Can you get FileInfo from your mailItem ?

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri I am not sure what you mean with that. `mailitem` is from type `Outlook.MailItem`

Comment: You have to do this before you create the mail item

Comment: @SebastianL I am not following. The mailitem that i want to compress in a zip is not created but more like passed to me.

Comment: a mail item is a whole email, so you are attaching a mail to a mail. So either you are doing something very wrong or you haven't understood the Outlook API in the slightest. Please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem and: https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add#syntax its vba, but you can transalte it 1 to 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to save :

```
 String savepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\" + filename + ".msg";
    mailItem.SaveAs(savepath);
 FileInfo mailItemToCompress= new FileInfo(savepath);
```

Compress :

```
public void Compress(FileInfo mailItemToCompress, string compressedMailItem)
{
    using (FileStream originalFileStream = mailItemToCompress.OpenRead())
    {
       using (FileStream compressedMailItem= File.Create(compressedMailItem)
            {
                using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Then attach your mailItem:

```
mailItem.Attachments.Add(compressedMailItem);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test this tomorrow. Is there a simple way to delete the mailitem after saving and compressing it (`mailitem.Delete()`? I guess it only deletes the actual mail item like this.